# Best way to update/translate the values of a field mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I need to update/translate a field called `status_id` on my mysql table, basically following this:

```
WHERE | SHOULD BE
  0   |    0
  1   |    1
  2   |    4
  3   |    8
  4   |    9
  5   |   10
  6   |    6
  7   |    2
  8   |   11
```

I've though of a few methods, but i'm not sure which one would be the best

The first one:

Use some transition elements, in this case, the desired final value+100

```sql
UPDATE myTable
SET status_id = 100
WHERE status_id = 0;

-- ...

UPDATE myTable
SET status_id = 111
WHERE status_id = 8;

-- ...

UPDATE myTable
SET status_id = 0
WHERE status_id = 100;

-- ...

UPDATE myTable
SET status_id = 11
WHERE status_id = 111;
```

The second one:

use `CASE`

```
UPDATE myTable SET status_id = 
CASE 
    WHEN status_id = 0 THEN 0
    -- ...
    WHEN status_id = 8 THEN 11
    ELSE status_id
END
```

This will only be done once, i just want to make sure i do not mess this up (I have backups, but it's always good to not need them)

Comment: I'd personally use a `CASE` statement to explicitly change them all in one `UPDATE`.  You can check, and double-check, the status changes there and run it as a single transaction.  Backup your table or DB first, just in case.

Comment: The `case` is the right option. There is not a `decode` function on mySql.

Answer (score 2):

For MySql 8.0+ you can create a CTE that returns each pair of current and new `status_id` and join it to the table in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
WITH cte(status_id, new_status_id) AS (VALUES
  ROW(0, 0),
  ROW(1, 1),
  ROW(2, 4),
  ROW(3, 8),
  ROW(4, 9),
  ROW(5, 10),
  ROW(6, 6),
  ROW(7, 2),
  ROW(8, 11)
)
UPDATE myTable t
INNER JOIN cte c ON c.status_id = t.status_id
SET t.status_id = c.new_status_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=990f2e878941c9b1aeb8b7c1df4acff2).

For prior versions join a subquery to the table:

```
UPDATE myTable t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 0 status_id, 0 new_status_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 11
) c ON c.status_id = t.status_id
SET t.status_id = c.new_status_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60dfeeb48b19a8eaf751397b4c12fbfa).

Note that I don't see any reason to keep where both values are equal, but MySql will not perform update in such a case.

Comment: Several of us are circling the same concept.  (Put all rows in a "holder" and then do the update).  Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have some extra fun, you can use MySQL's JSON capabilities:

```
UPDATE myTable SET status_id = JSON_EXTRACT(
    CAST('
        {
            "0": 0,
            "1": 1,
            "2": 4,
            "3": 8,
            "4": 9,
            "5": 10,
            "6": 6,
            "7": 2,
            "8": 11
        }'
        AS JSON
    ),
    CONCAT('$."', status_id, '"')
)
```

It can actually be more convenient to write and maintain (and in some cases also cleaner and simpler to construct automatically in code).

Comment: Several of us are circling the same concept.  (Put all rows in a "holder" and then do the update).  Upvote.  But this is definitely "extra fun" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your values in a "holder table".

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (before_value int, after_value int) ENGINE=MEMORY; 


/* populate your my_temp_table with your cross-walk values */
INSERT INTO my_temp_table (before_value, after_value)
  SELECT 101, 201 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 102, 202 FROM DUAL;
```

(etc, etc, i'm giving example values, put in your own real values.)

```
Update myTable
Set status_id = my_temp_table.after_value
from myTable , my_temp_table
Where
myTable.status_id = my_temp_table.before_value
```

That means you have "matches" that are not ambiguous.

The above is (one) "set based" approach.

If you have to do it sequentially (aka, you can't do the second update until the first update has been completed), you have to update one by one (also known as Row by Agonizing Row) RBAR.

REFERENCE:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET status_id = FIND_IN_SET(status_id, '1,7,x,2,x,6,x,3,4,5,8')
WHERE status_id BETWEEN 0 AND 8;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5dd617361fcf6a3d2d669625dc809db1

PS. This is a special case which allows such special solution.